# MOSS 2007 SP3 not showing in Windows Update

Tags: 2007, service-pack

I have MOSS 2007 SP2 on my machines. Since SP3 is already out for quite some time, it should be available via Windows Update. However when I try to look for a windows update, I cannot find anything related to SharePoint 2007.

Is there something I need to enable to update it via windows update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SharePoint (or most other 'server products' for that matter) are deployed by Windows Update.

You can download updates here and manually install

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839